# No option to specify branch name when creating container from repo in GCP

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

The option does appear when creating build trigger or using Cloud Run.

Does the platform assume `master` is my `main`?

[image: container creation screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It will pull and build from whatever the [default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch) for your git repo.